# Disable Anonymous Authentication results in Access denied/401 on root site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, anonymous-authentication

I disabled the anonymous access in IIS 8 / Authentication hosting SharePoint 2013. Now when I browse  to `http://sharepoint13/` I get a "This page has not been shared with you".
When I browse to `http://sharepoint13/pages/default.aspx` it works.
I experience the same issue when using sharepoint web services.

Can anyone explain me why disabling anonymous authentication causes this?

Comment: You're disabling Anonymous authentication in IIS? Is the web application using claims authentication? If so, my understanding is that with claims IIS passes the users to SharePoint to handle the authentication. To do this, you require anonymous authentication at the IIS level. I'm not sure why /pages/default.aspx would work though.

Comment: Yes I disabled it directly in IIS and I use claims.

Comment: You should turn anonymous authentication in IIS back on as this is required to support claims. Anonymous in IIS does not explicitly equate to anonymous in SharePoint.